# Retrieve results as single string each time a method is called in java

Tags: java, swing

I want to retrieve the results of a method in a single string each time the function is called. I have a method which returns different results every time. I want to put all the results as a single string.

Tried to use append() method of java but the results are getting replaced every time as the function is called each time. but i need to retrieve the previous results as well.

my code is as follows.

```
public void createPanel2()
    {
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        query = new JLabel("query");
        textbox =new JTextField(10);

        submit = new JButton("submit");
        panel2.add(query);
        panel2.add(textbox);
        panel2.add(submit);

        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String str =textbox.getText();
                String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1";
                SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(serverUrl);
                try {
                    for (SolrDocument next : simpleSolrQuery(solr, str +
                            "")) {
                        prettyPrint(System.out, next);
                    }
                } catch (SolrServerException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                initFilterAndButton();
            }
            SolrDocumentList simpleSolrQuery(SolrServer solr,
                    String query) throws SolrServerException {
                SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery(query);
                //SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(searchTerm);
                //query.setStart((pageNum - 1) * numItemsPerPage);
                //query.setRows(numItemsPerPage);

                //solrQuery.setRows(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                QueryResponse resp = solr.query(solrQuery);


                //System.out.println("resp"+resp);
                final SolrDocumentList hits = resp.getResults();
                /*for (SolrDocument d : hits) {
                    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> i = d.iterator(); i
                            .hasNext();) {
                        Map.Entry<String, Object> e2 = i.next();
                        System.out.println(e2.getKey() + "\t" + e2.getValue());
                    }

                    System.out.println("------------------------");
                }*/

                System.out.println("hits"+resp.getElapsedTime());
                System.out.println("size"+hits.size());
                System.out.println("num found"+hits.getNumFound());
                //String str ="hello";
                //createPanel1(hits);
                return hits;



            }

            void prettyPrint(PrintStream out, SolrDocument doc) {
                List<String> sortedFieldNames =
                        new ArrayList<String>(doc.getFieldNames());
                Collections.sort(sortedFieldNames);
                out.println();
            //  StringBuilder contentstring=new StringBuilder();
            //  ArrayList<String> contents=new ArrayList<>();
                for (String field : sortedFieldNames) {
                    if(field.equals("content")){
                    textarea.append(String.format("%s: %s",
                            field,doc.getFieldValue(field)+"\n"));
                    out.println(String.format("\t%s: %s",
                            field, doc.getFieldValue(field)));
                    contentsmethod(doc.getFieldValue(field).toString());
                //  contents.add(doc.getFieldValue(field).toString());
                //  System.out.println("conetnts"+contentstring);
                    }

                }
            //  String test=contentstring.toString();


                out.println();
            }
            public void contentsmethod(String fieldsvalues) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                StringBuilder contentstring=new StringBuilder();
                contentstring.append(fieldsvalues);
                 try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(serverQuery+URLEncoder.encode(contentstring.toString())).toURI());
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        });




    }
```

The code above is calling the prettyPrint method every time and the results of that method should be retrieved to a single string which should hold the previous called results as well.

here i want to retrieve the results of  contentstring.append(fieldsvalues); 
But contentstring is returning only the current results and not appending the previous results.

this is obvious because the method is called everytime. Is there any work around to retrieve the previous results along with the current ones as well.

Comment: Why don't you use an static arraylist and add the "contentstring" every time you have it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move this `StringBuilder contentstring=new StringBuilder();` outside of your method. Every time your method call is made, you create a new String. This is why you only get the current value.

Comment: I created the Stringbuilder outside my method but still the same I am getting only the current value

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `List` outside of your method and add the resulting `String` in that list. Otherwhise, you can create the string outside and append the results to it without instantiating a new one at every method call.

You have to do something like this:

```
StringBuilder contentstring = new StringBuilder();

            public void contentsmethod(String fieldsvalues) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                contentstring.append(fieldsvalues);
                 try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(serverQuery+URLEncoder.encode(contentstring.toString())).toURI());
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                   }

             }
```

Comment: I tried both and I get the same results its not working.

Comment: I edited my answer with code. Have you tried with something like that?

Comment: Yes i have done the same. Thanks a lot!!! Now its appending but i need to send the final appended value to the URL. Now its sending the value to the url each time when its appended. But i want the final appended result alone to be passed to URL.

Comment: You can do the `contentstring.append( doc.getFieldValue(field).toString() )` in the `prettyPrint` method and call `contentsmethod( contentstring.toString() )` just when you have the final value.